# How do I add a button on fragment layout?(Google maps Android studio)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

This is my `maps_activity.xml` file and when I try to add a button field I get an error `Multiple root tags`.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

When I try to add

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="146dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Open Store" />
```

I get an error message `Multiple root tags`.

My MapsActivity class up until the `onCreate` method

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener{

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    Marker marker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Map Location Activity");

        mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);

    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Each XML layout file can only have one "root" tag. Often this will be some sort of `ViewGroup`; common examples include `LinearLayout`, `FrameLayout`, `ConstraintLayout`, and `RelativeLayout`.

The right one to choose depends on what your desired goals are. Considering that you've mentioned only a Google map and a `Button`, the question to ask is whether you want these two things to appear next to each other (or above/below each other) or on top of each other.

If you want them to be above/below each other, choose `LinearLayout`, and write something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="146dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Open Store"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If instead you want the button to float on top of the map, change `LinearLayout` to `FrameLayout` (and remove the `orientation` attribute, since framelayouts don't have an orientation).

Either way, you have to adhere to the rule that all layouts can only have a single root. That doesn't mean that all layouts can only have one view, but as soon as you have more than one, you have to figure out a good box to put them all in.

Answer (score 0):

try relative or linear layout as a parent and add fragment and button inside parent layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.commonutils.MapsActivity" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GO" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]